# Arcpy connecting points with lines using coordinates

Tags: arcpy

Based on another post, I wrote a Python script that reads coordinates, creates points, and then connects them. Here is the code:

```
import arcpy

in_rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(r"C:\Users\cchen\Documents\temp\test.gdb\linetest")

point = arcpy.Point()
array = arcpy.Array()

featureList = []
cursor = arcpy.InsertCursor(r"C:\Users\cchen\Documents\temp\test.gdb\newlines")
feat = cursor.newRow()

for in_row in in_rows:
    # Set X and Y for start and end points
    point.X = in_row.sx
    point.Y = in_row.sy
    array.add(point)
    point.X = in_row.ex
    point.Y = in_row.ey
    array.add(point)   
    # Create a Polyline object based on the array of points
    polyline = arcpy.Polyline(array)
    # Clear the array for future use
    array.removeAll()
    # Append to the list of Polyline objects
    featureList.append(polyline)
    # Insert the feature
    feat.shape = polyline
    cursor.insertRow(feat)
del feat
del cursor
```

It gives me this error message:
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 14, in 
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects_base.py", line 89, in _set
    return setattr(self._arc_object, attr_name, cval(val))
RuntimeError: Point: Input value is not numeric

Since the field is numeric(double), I am confused on why this does not work.

Comment: You need to create more than one Point (inside the loop), since this code just moves one point around and attempts to create a line with only one (repeating) vertex. You should use a DA cursor for an order of magnitude performance benefit, and the Polyline constructor shoild include a SpatialReference.

Comment: try converting "in_row.sx", "in_row.sy","in_row.ex","in_row.ey" to float. i.e. float(in_row.sx).  That error is probably becasue the ex,ey,sx, and sy values are strings.

Comment: You might be able to use "XY to Line" to create your 2 point lines.